# css centering element within wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I need to center num 4,5 block when screen resolution is 768.
please see my screenshot and my source code.

**Current View**
[image]

**What it should be**

[image]

Here is my code

```
            <div class="home-property-list">
                <div class="prop-sub">
                    <div class="home-property-list-item">1</div>
                    <div class="home-property-list-item">2</div>
                    <div class="home-property-list-item">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="prop-sub">
                    <div class="home-property-list-item">4</div>
                    <div class="home-property-list-item">5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS Styles

```
.home-property-list{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
.home-property-list-item{
    width: 19.6%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.2%;
    background: #F00;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
.prop-sub{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.home-property-list-item{
    width: 32.9%;
}
}
```

Comment: On .home-property-list-item use display:inline-block; instead of float:left; and apply text-align-center on .home-property-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/AcQvq/)

You need to add `text-align:center` to the wrapper `div` then ensure the child elemtns have `display:inline-block;`

Change your CSS to (for example):

```
.home-property-list {
    width: 100%;
}
.prop-sub{    
    text-align:center;
}
.home-property-list-item {
    width: 19.6%;    
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #F00;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .prop-sub {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .home-property-list-item {
        width: 32.9%;
    }
```